# EXEC function truncating the string variable to be executed

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-sql

I need to output a different number of columns depending on the value of some variables in different columns. At its most basic, I have to output either X number of columns, or X+1

I have created a stored proc, set the column X+1 to be a variable, and set the final result as a string variable as the shown in the code below for illustration purposes.

CREATE PROC MyProc.dynamicProc
AS

BEGIN

```
DECLARE 
@myVar          VARCHAR(75)

SELECT  @myVar = myVar FROM myTaBLE
.
.
.
.
DECLARE @RESULT VARCHAR(MAX)

SET  @RESULT = 'SELECT  
                    COL1,
                    COL2,
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    COLN'+
                    @myVar+
                    'COLN+1,
                    .
                    .
                    COLN+X
FROM                #SOMEtABLE

ORDER BY            COL1,
                    COL2'


EXECUTE (@finalSelect)
```

END;
GO

when I print @finalSelect, I see the string is truncated at 'ORDER BY CO' for example. The length of @finalSelect varies between 4800 and 4820 depending on the value of @myVar. Is this something that anyone has had to deal with before? When I lessen the number of columns the stored proc works as expected and I get the result set expected without any errors. I know I can lessen the number of characters in the aliases and all that but I'm just working around the problem, without understanding it. I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Cast every component of your query to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` before concatenating. Recent versions of SQL Server don't seem to need this if at least one of the components is `MAX`, but on earlier ones it's quite easy to get an implicit conversion and truncation to smaller types if they're mixed into the expression. Note also that `PRINT` always truncates and can't be used as a reliable means of checking the result, and even Management Studio will truncate results depending on configuration after you take that hurdle.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have cast every component to NVARCHAR(MAX) but not the string is being truncated shorter!

Comment: I have shortened my ORDERED BY to just a few fields, executed the sp and it was fine. Remarkably however, I put everything back as it was, i.e. varchar(75) for the first variables and varchar(MAX) for final select and now everything is working. I am surely not satisfied with inconsistency and mystery around it though...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem comes from the concatenation with the `@MyVar` variable.
Even if  `@Result` is a `VARCHAR(MAX)`, the strings you concatenate are not. So the result of concatenation is a "small" truncated `VARCHAR` that you store into a "big" , but then useless, `VARCHAR(MAX)`.
Thus, you should define `VARCHAR(MAX)` variables for each part you concatenate and then assign to `@Result`

Comment: I have, and when I do the string @result is actually truncated much shorter than before.

Comment: The exact same code is now functioning properly... This actually made it more difficult because the result is not consistent